# Laravel Microservices & RabbitMQ

Tags: laravel, rabbitmq, microservices

Just wondering what the best way of capturing "fanout" calls from RabbitMQ is in Laravel subscriber services?

Service 1 sends out the message, say UserUpdated with their UUID, and this goes into RabbitMQ now.

Service 2/3/4/n capture UserUpdated and perform their appropriate actions.

I just don't know the best way to have a long running service on the Laravel subscribers to catch these messages and perform their own actions. I've tried multiple packages on GitHub so far but none go into this detail of where to place a class to receive the messages.

All help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that with [enqueue/laravel-queue](https://github.com/php-enqueue/laravel-queue) package. It comes with Enqueue Simple Client support. The client supports, pub/sub, message bus and friendly for use in microservers oriented systems.